# SSL certificate with error "Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 192.168.56.74 "

Tags: ssl-certificate-errors

I configured a root and intermediate CA using MS2012. I encountered error when I accessing the apache webserver using the SSL Certificate issued by the CA.

The error is
"Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 192.168.56.74 "
I have followed the apache SSL configuration guide to add following in ssl.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/ssl/elabCA.pem

The following message shown under Advance from Chrome browser.
192.168.56.74 normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to 192.168.56.74 this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials.

Anyone encountered this before? appreciate could share some hints whether caused by Apache config or CA config. I can share the certificate info using openssl x509 -text -noout -in xx.cer

Comment: Please do, without seeing the certificate nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create all the Root and Intermediate CAs and issue certificates from them for your servers all day..  but the browser you use to connect to those servers is not going to trust those certificates until they're explicity told to do so.

You have to either import the Root CA into the client/browers's trusted root store, or have the server certificate signed by a public CA; i.e. one that's already in your client/browser's trusted root store.

If this is for a public facing site, you can get free signed certificates that are trusted by most browsers from letsencrypt.org.  If this is for an internal site, and it will normally be viewed by users from PCs that you manage through a Domain Controller, you can push your Root CA out to them through domain policy.